Oracle Apex: size of Right side column
I'm using APEX 23.1 with Redwood Light Theme.
I need to increase the width of the "Actions Column" (Right Side Column) but in the theme roller there isn't option like other themes have. Is there a way to increase this?

I tried some Inline CSS but it isn't working as it should.
example:
.t-Body-actions {
   width: 540px
}

:not(.u-RTL) .t-PageBody.js-rightCollapsed .t-Body-actions {
   transform: translate3d(540px, 0, 0)!important
}

:not(.u-RTL) ​.t-PageBody.js-rightExpanded.t-PageBody--hideLeft .t-Body-main {
    margin-right: 540px!important
}

:not(.u-RTL) .t-PageBody.js-rightExpanded.t-PageBody--hideLeft .t-Body-title {
   right: 540px;
}


Which page template is that ?

I'm assuming you are talking about the page template "Right Side Column". Inspect the actions column with browser dev tools and you'll see that the "width" attribute is set by a css variable "--ut-body-actions-width". css variables are a common pattern in APEX since version 22.1.

This information can then be used to customize the page, by setting some css in the "Page attributes > CSS > Inline".
For example:
:root {   
  --ut-body-actions-width: 540px;
}

